# Run apps on unique mesos-slaves

Tags: mesos, marathon

I am running two different apps on a Mesos-cluster using Marathon. I want these apps to be launched on different slaves always (even while scaling up). Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a `UNIQUE` operator in Marathon. More details here: https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/master/docs/docs/constraints.md

Comment: UNIQUE operator will only make sure that tasks/instances of the same app are on different nodes. However, I want different apps to be on unique nodes. I got a better (not the best) solution here: https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/2330

Comment: I see, sorry, I didn't carefully read your question first. I think tagging is fine, though it statically assigns potential agents to your app. An alternative could be to pack your spark master and slave binaries together and launch one of those. This approach however requires you to somehow decide on the agent, which binary to start.